# Excel Userform Multicolumn ListBox Not Updating

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have a userform with a multi-column listbox populated from a 2D array. The purpose of the userform is to allow the user to see and edit basic information for a list of clients using a combination of textboxes and checkboxes. The listbox is used to select a single client to view the data inputs for that client. When a client is selected, a group of textboxes and checkboxes are populated based on the data in the list (originally from the array). If the user makes any changes to the client data as tracked by the userform, it will ask if they want to save. If they say yes, the original data array is edited and the listbox should be updated to reflect the edits.

To populate the listbox, I have a single procedure that populates the list from the array data. I am using this procedure in the when the userform is initialized and when updates are made by the user.

However, I am running into an odd issue. When a user edits the data and the program repopulates the listbox, the listbox itself doesn't visually reflect the changes and still reflects the original data. I say visually because it appears it updates the list because when I select the edited client record from the list, the edited data shows correctly in the associated text boxes and check boxes as if the listbox had been changed. Even weirder, if I close the userform and reinitialize it, the listbox will then show the changes.

My current method to update the listbox is as follows where LB_Names is the listbox name and clientList is the 2d Array with 10 columns.

```
colWidths = "15,60,60,20,20,20,20,20,50,50"
With Me.LB_Names
'.Clear
.List = clientList
.ColumnCount = UBound(clientList, 2)
.ColumnWidths = colWidths
End With
```

I commented out the ".clear"command because it would result in the listbox not being populated at all even though the backend data was updated properly. The clientList variable is an 2D Variant/Variant Array.

I was able to get the list to show if I added the following code to a separate button and clicked this after running the above code. For some reason, this works if I click a button afterward vs adding it in various locations in the original code.

```
colWidths = "15,60,60,20,20,20,20,20,50,50"
Me.LB_Names.ColumnWidths = colWidths
```

I do require that the listbox is updated from an array and not linked to a range or some other form. The array will always be 2 dimensional.

Thank you!

I tried to update the listbox data from the user entries but the changes were not reflected in the final listbox.

Comment: If there is `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` in your code, you could comment it and try again.

Comment: Tried `Me.Repaint`?

Comment: How about you move the `.List` to the bottom?

Comment: I tried the Application.ScreenUpdating and Me.Repaint without success and also tried reordering the commands but no luck.

Comment: I did some rearranging of the entire userform and think I solved the issue though. Previously, I was trying to update the listbox in the listbox change event. I think this was throwing off an error. I've since moved the listbox update to the mousedown and that seems to have solved the issue.